# React/Jest hook test, state is not always updated

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

Component state and functions

```
const [eventList, setEventList] = useState(events)
 const toggleSelect = (event: CalendarEventType):void => {
        event.selected = !event.selected
 }

 const addEvent = (event: CalendarEventType): void => {
    event.id = uuid()
    setEventList(prevState => [...prevState, event])
 }
```

Test

```
const {result} = renderHook((initialProps) => useCalendarEvent(initialProps), {initialProps: exampleEvent})

describe('Event management', () => {
    test('Select and unselect event', async () => {
        result.current.toggleSelect(result.current.eventList[0])
        expect(result.current.eventList[0].selected).toBeTruthy()
    })
    test('Add event', async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            result.current.addEvent({title: 'TestAdd', start: new Date()})
        })
        expect(result.current.eventList).toHaveLength(2)
    })
    test('log', () => {
        console.log(result.current.eventList)
    })
})
```

If I run these tests, the second one fails and the console.log returns a single event, but if I put the contents of "Add event" in the first test function, it work.

Otherwise if I put the "Add event" test before the "Select and unselect event" test, that works too, but I'd like to be able to test before and after adding events.

Answer (score 2):

You are using await act(async () => {...}) to handle the asynchronous addEvent function. However, it's possible that the asynchronous operation is not completing before the subsequent test runs

```
describe('Event management', () => {
  test('Add event', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      result.current.addEvent({ title: 'TestAdd', start: new Date() });
    });
    expect(result.current.eventList).toHaveLength(2);
  });

  test('Select and unselect event', () => {
    act(() => {
      result.current.toggleSelect(result.current.eventList[0]);
    });
    expect(result.current.eventList[0].selected).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('log', () => {
    console.log(result.current.eventList);
  });
});
```

Comment: What's strange is that the addEvent function doesn't seem to be executed if I place the test after another, I've tried adding a useEffect in my component with a console.log to watch eventList mutation and it was never triggered